# How to await an async debounce function?

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, async-await, vuejs3, debouncing

I'm trying to await an async debounce API call. But the await is not working. It logs `'Awaited'` instantly. What am I doing wrong?

My onMounted in setup:

```
onMounted(async () => {
  console.log('Awaiting');
  const fetchAbsentiesAsync = await apiCallConst();
  await Promise.all([fetchAbsentiesAsync]);
  console.log('Awaited');

  isLoading.value = false;
});
```

My API call:

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

const apiCallConst = debounce(async () => {
  await ApiService.makeApiCall()
    .then((data) => {
      state.data = data;
    })
}, 10000);
```

ApiService.makeApiCall:

```
  async makeApiCall(): Promise<string> {
    return {
      data: await apiFetch(`group/data`, {
        method: HttpMethods.POST,
      }),
    };
  }
```

Comment: We can't see the definition of your `debounce` function so we can't tell how it interacts with a function that returns a promise.

Comment: The await property resolve your fonction. Not sur is this will solve your problem, but you need to remove the promise all and only execute this ```const fetchAbsentiesAsync = await apiCallConst();``` If you log fetchAbsentiesAsync, the response is inside.

Comment: Use promise-aware debounce.

Comment: @Ruben — No, you've added a function called `ApiService.makeApiCall` to your question. I said your `debounce` function was missing.

Comment: @Quentin default debounce from Lodash

Comment: `await Promise.all([fetchAbsentiesAsync]);` makes no sense - `fetchAbsentiesAsync` is not a promise, you already `await`ed the `apiCallConst()`!

Comment: Like everyone says we don't know the debounce function. A quick google shows that debounce from iodash is not an async function, which await has no effect on.

Answer (score -1):

The reason your code logs 'Awaited' instantly is because the debounced function itself `apiCallConst` is a synchronous function which `await` has no effect on.

If you need to perform some action after the debounced function has finished executing, you should handle it inside the debounced function or use a callback mechanism.

Here's an example of a callback implementation:

```
onMounted(async () => {
  console.log('Awaiting');
  const fetchAbsentiesAsync = await apiCallConst(() => {
    console.log('Awaited');
    isLoading.value = false;
  });
});

import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

const apiCallConst = debounce(async (callback) => {
  await ApiService.makeApiCall()
    .then((data) => {
      state.data = data;
      callback();
    })
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Standard debounce functions like the one from lodash absolutely don't care whether the callback function they were passed is anonymous or not.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, I had not finished testing. Please re-review.

Comment: Not any better. OP doesn't even use React! Please re-read their question.

Comment: @Bergi I see OP's actual problem now, updated.